# Building Node.js Modular Web Application

Tags: node.js, module, express

How can I build a modular web application using Node.js? What modules should I use to write it? I'm using express MVC does this considered as modular system?

Comment: [This screencast](http://vimeo.com/56166857) created by TJ Holowaychuk author of Express, Jade, Stylus and Mocha describes how you can use Express' app mounting feature to create modular self-contained applications.

Comment: I think the screencast pointed to by @SPP below is a better way to separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look at the Express "Route Separation" example:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/route-separation